# Can we write values to StrongAuthenticationEmailAddress attribute in Azure B2C using powershell or C sharp code

Tags: powershell, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c

Can we update "StrongAuthenticationEmailAddress" attribute used by EMAIL MFA using PowerShell / Graph Explorer or using C# code?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can as per [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/proofing-up-users-programmatically-on-azure-ad-b2c-using-either-email-or-phone-71a71f579235).

Calling the methods creates "StrongAuthenticationEmailAddress" in the background.

Comment: That article is set to private

Comment: Apologies - link fixed.